# Why does $ord_p(a^i) =ord_p(a) = d $ when $(i,d)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I'm having a bit of a hard time wrapping my head around why this theorem is true.

Suppose p is prime and $ord_p(a) = d$. For each natural number $i$ with $(i,d) = 1 ,ord_p(a^i) =d$

My thought process was that if $a^d \equiv 1 \rightarrow a^{id} \equiv 1$ wouldn't that make $d$ the order still? Is my proof valid?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046859/show-that-a5-is-a-primitive-root-mod-p-implies-a-is-a-primitive-root-mod-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! Your proof shows that if $ord_p(a) = d$ then $ord_p(a^i) \mid d$, since there could be some smaller $k \mid d$, $k < d$ such that $a^{i k} \equiv 1$. To finish, you can argue that $a^{ik} \equiv 1$ implies $d \mid ik$ since the order of $a$ is $d$. But $(i,d) = 1$, so $d \mid k$, and hence $d = k$. So the order of $a^i$ is $d$.

For a more concrete example of why this extra argument is necessary, notice that your proof didn't use the fact that $(i,d) = 1$ anywhere. So consider $a=3$ mod $7$. Then you can check that $ord_7 (3) = 6$, and try $i=3$. Importantly, $(3,6) \neq 1$. We have $3^3 = 6$, and clearly the order of $6$ is $2$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, I knew I had to use $(i,d) = 1$ somehow, but I wasn't sure how.

Comment: @CuriousStudent I've added a little more detail, hope this helped!