# If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $37$, which of the numbers $g^2, g^3,.., g^8$ is a primitive root modulo 37?

Tags: roots

If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $37$, which of the numbers $g^2, g^3,.., g^8$ is a primitive root modulo $37$?

This problem is a problem bothering me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which of the exponents is coprime with $\;\varphi(37)\;$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Like [Order of elements modulo p](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220493/order-of-elements-modulo-p)

OR

[If $\operatorname{ord}_ma=10$, find $\operatorname{ord}_ma^6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229150/if-operatornameord-ma-10-find-operatornameord-ma6?lq=1) ,

ord$_pa=d\implies$ ord $_p(a^k)=\dfrac d{(k,d)}$

Now $g$ is primitive root $\pmod{37}\iff $ord$_{37}(g)=\phi(37)=36$

$\implies$ord $_{37}(g^k)=\dfrac{36}{(k,36)}$

So, we need $(k,36)=1$ to keep ord$_{37}(g^k)=36$

Comment: when you say $(k, 36 )$ do you mean $gcd(k, 36)$ ?

Comment: @Pasie15, Definitely. This is a common symbol for GCD