# If $a$ is of order $3$ mod a prime $p$, then ...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, primitive-roots

The question says:

> Prove that if $a$ is of order $3$ modulo a prime $p$, then $1+a+a^2\equiv 0 \pmod p$. Moreover, $a+1$ is of order $6$.

## For the First Part:

The typical idea is to start with $a^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p \to a^3 -1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$. Factoring the term on the left hand side, the rest is straightforward.

**However**, I need to check the following idea:

> $$1+a+a^2 \equiv a^3+a^2+a \equiv a(1+a+a^2)\equiv a^2(1+a+a^2)$$
>   $$\equiv a^3(1+a+a^2) \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
>
> *Since, by the hypothesis, $a^3$ cannot be zero modulo the prime $p$, the desired result holds.*

If this idea holds true, it can be generalized to the following result:

> if $a$ is of order $k$, then, modulo prime $p$, then $1+a+a^2+\cdots + a^{k-1}$ is divisible by $p$.

Is it??

## For the Second Part:

I can see that:

$$1+a+a^2 \equiv 0 \to 1+a \equiv -a^2 \pmod p$$

However, does this implies anything? Given that $a$ is of order $3$, but what about $-a$??

Please Help, and Thanks in advance,,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220493/order-of-elements-modulo-p

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, I would like to see your comments about thoughts on the first part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second part, taking from the first part that $1+a = -a^2\pmod p\implies (1+a)^6= (-a^2)^6 = a^{12}\pmod p= (a^3)^4 =1^4\pmod p=1\pmod p$ . Thus $1+a$ is of order $6$ as claimed. And if $a$ is of order $3$ then $(-a)^3 = -a^3 = -1 = p-1\pmod p$. And from this we have: $(-a)^6 = ((-a)^3)^2 = (-1)^2 = 1\pmod p$. So $-a$ is of order $6$ as well.

Comment: Thanks, but how to be sure that $6$ is the least power congruent to $1 \pmod p$ for $(1+a)$??

Comment: I need also to make sure my thoughts are correct for the first part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MagedSaeed: You can prove it yourself that if $k$ is such that $(a+1)^k = 1\pmod p \implies k = 6$. In fact, such $k$ must satisfies $k \mid 6 \implies k = 1,2,3$. And none of these can satisfy since $a$ is of order $3$.

Comment: Oh, thanks,, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Using geometrical sum formula we get

$$1+a+a^2 = \frac{a^3-1}{a-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$

And generally we get

$$1+a+a^2+\dots + a^{k-1}= \frac{a^k-1}{a-1} \equiv 0 \pmod p$$