# Finding all no-congruent primitive roots $\pmod{29}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, primitive-roots

> Finding all no-congruent primitive roots $\pmod{29}$.

I have found that $2$ is a primitve root $\pmod{29}$
Then I found that is it 12 no-congruent roots, since $\varphi(\varphi(29)) = 12$
Then I found that:

$r_1=2^1=2\bmod (29)\\r_2=2^3=8\bmod (29)\\r_3=2^5=3\bmod (29)\\r_4=2^{11}=18\bmod (29)\\r_ 5=2^{13}=18\bmod (29)\\r_6=2^{17}=21\bmod (29)\\r_7=2^{19}=21\bmod (29)\\r_8=2^{23}=10\bmod (29)\\r_9=2^{27}=15\bmod (29)\\r_{10}=2^{29}=2\bmod (29)$

Is $10$ of these roots $12$ roots. Took the power of the primes from $1-29$ (not the primefactors of $\varphi,\ 2$ and $7$), but I am missing $2$ roots, and I don't understand how to find them. I have used all prime powers.

Comment: Why are you sticking to prime exponents?  $\gcd(9,28)=1$ so $2^9$ is a primitive root, for instance.  Note:  it's just an accident of small numbers that most of the numbers in $\{1,2,\cdots, 28\}$ which are prime to $28$ happen to be prime.

Comment: Thank you, was sticking to prime, but relative primes gives much more sense :) @lulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use all powers of $2$ that are *relatively prime* to $28$.

The two roots you are missing are $2^9$ and $2^{15}.$

$9$ and $15$ are not prime (they are multiples of $3$), but they share no factors with $28$.

---

(I also note that you have wrong values for $2^{13}$ and $2^{19}\bmod29$;

they aren't the same as $2^{11}$ and $2^{17}$, respectively.)

---

Also, you are missing $2^{25}$; you have $2^{29}$, which is the same as $2^{1}\bmod28$, instead.

Comment: Great user :-). Hi.

Answer (score 2):

Like my answer here [Order of elements modulo p](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220493/order-of-elements-modulo-p),

We can say $2^r$ is a primitive root of $29$ 
iff $$(r,\phi(29))=1$$

Now $$\phi(\phi(29))=\phi(7)\cdot\phi(4)=?$$